# Is it possible to have a Resource folder in a published C# project?

Tags: c#, winforms, publish

I have a question which will probably be quite vague.

I'm developing a Windows Forms application in C# that can read and write games to an Access database. Every game has an attribute that links to an Image in the resource folder.

While debugging I was able to just read and write my screenshots to the following path:

```
"..\\..\\Resources\\Screenshots\\";
```

I tried publishing my application earlier today to test if it would still work and if not, to locate the path where the Resource folder would be when published.

So far I have the feeling that the resources just get burned into the exe file or one of the other files it generates.

Is it in any way possible to have a real folder in the published version of an application from which I can keep reading and writing my images like I did while debugging?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your screenshots will be compiled into the assembly as resources when publising.

As for the real folder, you can absolutely do that. Make sure you give your app the right path to that folder.

Comment: Thanks for the quck reply.
I can't seem to find the folder though, is there a way to locate it?

Comment: I don't understand... Sorry :s Could you maybe give an example?

Comment: @MathiasBoeckx sorry, you wont see the folder because it is compiled into assembly. you want to read/write to a screenshot folder you would use the a real folder. ressource is meant for things like your app icons, or stuff that you wont be touching